# Palatal itching and rhinitis

Tags: allergy, common-cold, itching

It is a common finding among people that palatal itching is usually followed by rhinitis.
In a [study](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.jcmad.com/admin/pdf/718.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiujb2-kv7pAhUelEsFHQJ6BagQFjANegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2ogzfaEJ-qvNF5xNKsOJGU) it was found that palatal itching and allergic rhinitis are related.

My question is that why does the palate itch during rhinitis? What is the science behind it?
I searched about it but couldn't find it anywhere.
Also is it only associated with allergic rhinitis or it also happens in non allergic rhinitis?